# Audio conversation over ASP.NET page !

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, audio, voice

How can I create an `ASP.NET` page, that allows users to communicate with `audio voice`.

What must I do to accomplish this job.

Thanks.

Comment: Let your asp.net page show a phone book? ;)

Comment: This not the idea. I want to create an Audio Chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ASP.NET only? I'm not sure you can do this without some sort of browser plugin. I suspect that it might be advantageous to leverage the Flash Player to make the call. You'd still need a communication server to do the plumbing. Check out [Red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/) (Open Source), [FlashMediaServer](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) (Adobe's product), [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowzamedia.com/index.html) (cheaper than FMS).

Answer (score 0):

spender's answer is correct.  Current versions of HTML nor the proposed HTML5 provide any support for audio pick up.  Additionally, the audio playback features are insufficient to provide the kind of audio streaming controls that you will need.  Look at the variety of plug-in technologies available or write your own browser specific, operating specific plug in.

If you are going to target devices such as the iPad and iPhone that won't support plug-ins, you are going to be forced to build native applications for those platforms.